# How can I apply my site's master page to my blog?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a Sharepoint site that uses MasterPageA, with Subsite1 that inherits that master page from the parent (I think).  I have another Subsite blog under Subsite1, like this:

```
Master site 
  Subsite1
     Blog subsite
```

but I can't get the header and footer to be like the master.  I can't find a way to apply it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have two options**

1. in case, **the parent site is a publishing site**, you should do the following:

   - Open your Blog Site > Site Setting.
   - Site Actions > Manage site features.
   - Activate `SharePoint Server Publishing`.

[image]

- Go back to site setting > below `Look and Feel` > The `Master page` option should be shown now > click on it to change the Master Page.

[image]

- In **System** MasterPage, (**Not** Site MasterPage - It looks a SharePoint Bug) > select your Master Page (MasterA).

[image]

> **Note** you should be aware of activating `SharePoint Server Publishing` will lead to missing the `Save site as a template`. For more details check [MISSING
>   SAVE SITE AS TEMPLATE IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)

---

2. In case **the parent site is not Publishing Site** like Team Site, you should do the following.

   - Open your blog site via SharePoint Designer.
   - In the main page, click on Edit site Home Page.
   - From the above ribbon, > Click `Edit in Advanced Mode`.
   - At the Page directive, change the `MasterPageFile` and Pick up your MasterPage.

     ```
      <%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="../../_catalogs/masterpage/mqassas.master"
     ```